# SpreadsheetGear.ValidationType.List turn off

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I have a spreadsheetgear validation type list on one of the columns in a spreadsheet. The issue I have is when I reload the spreadsheet with different sets of data, I get an error that validation already exists. I don't know how to turn off the validation before reloading the new set of data. Please help.

Comment: You'll need to post some code so folks can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the scenario correctly, you could either:

1) Use [IValidation](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IValidation.html).[Delete](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IValidation~Delete.html)() to remove existing validation to the range prior to adding new validation.

```
worksheet.Cells["A:A"].Validation.Delete(); 
worksheet.Cells["A:A"].Validation.Add(...);
```

2) Instead of all out deleting the old one, modify the existing IRange.[Validation](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange_members.html) object to fit your new data set.  You would use [IValidation](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IValidation.html).[Modify](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IValidation~Modify.html)(...) to do this.